# Eclipse RCP Missing Constraint / Bundle Error

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When I try to execute my RCP application from within Eclipse I get the following error message:

```
com.bah.gs.arts.jekyll.plugins.VideoLog
    Missing Constraint: Required Bundle: com.bah.gs.arts.jekyll.plugins.JVLC_Runtime; bundle-version="0.9.1"
```

**Can someone tell me how I resolve this**?

Answer (score 37):

A good trick is also to go into the run configuration dialog in Eclipse, open the Plugins tab and click the "Magic" button "add required bundles", if this marks the window as having unsaved changes you know something was added and it might work :)

Answer (score 5):

From [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.rap/msg04655.html):
You could start by running your RCP application with a launch configuration including the "`-console`" command: that will offer you the `OSGi` console in the "`Console`" view. This only means that `OSGi` is running.

Should look like this:

```
OSGi>
```

If this is available, just type "`ss`" (for short status) and hit return. This will result in a list with all your bundles including their status. This information would be good to see in order to track down the problem.

You have also the article "[Where Is My Bundle](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Where_Is_My_Bundle)" for further informations.

---

Check also (especially if you cannot do the above, because the application just does not launch itself and only propose you to see the error logs) the **plugins dependencies** of your **product configuration**:
is `com.bah.gs.arts.jekyll.plugins.JVLC_Runtime` displayed there?

It is often related to an export list problem, as illustrated by [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg26126.html).

Comment: @Dr. Faust: you are welcome. You can also post an answer of your own reporting what you had to change in your project to make it work.