# Can not use SWT nebula widget in my application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nebula

I have installed Nebula Release in my Eclipse Juno.
I wanted to use `CDateTime` so I added a dependency in my `MANIFEST.MF` of my plugin project:
I.e. added: `org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.cdatetime` in the dependencies tab.
I also made sure that it is part of the dependencies of the corresponding `feature.xml` of Feature project.
But when I run my application I get:

> Missing Constraint: org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.cdatetime;
>   bundle-version="0.14.0"

Why is the nebula widget failing to be found?
What am I messing up here? Perhaps it is simple, but I am new in eclipse programming.

Comment: Try this: [Eclipse RCP Missing Constraint / Bundle Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028573/eclipse-rcp-missing-constraint-bundle-error)

Comment: @Baz:I checked your link.The answer of VonC would help if I did not know what bundle is causing the problem (but I know that it is `Nebula`).The answer of gromgull is about modifying `Run Time Configuration`.I have read that it is highly not-recomended to avoid modifying that.Am I wrong on this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Runtime configuration. Are you sure that the version number of the nebula bundle you include is the same as the one you require? i.e. are they both "0.14.0"?

Comment: @Baz:I installed `Nebula` to eclipse from `Install new Software` and used this link:http://download.eclipse.org/technology/nebula/snapshot/. Then from the dependencies of `MANIFEST` I chose the one available.Does this information help?

Comment: Ok, I did exactly the same with a fresh RCP project and it did work. Install nebula -> create new RCP project -> add dependency to plugin.xml dependencies. Maybe try creating a new dummy rcp project and see if it works there.

Comment: @Baz:I tried to add the dependency in an existing plugin project that I am currently working on.I will try it on a dummy rcp project as you advice to see if this works.

Comment: @Baz:I did not forget your comment on this.It is that I am not sure on how to test it since I am new in eclipse.I created an `RCP` project but no `Application.e4xmi` is created.Not sure how to add the parts.Do you have a tutorial for this?(Sorry if this is too newbie for you...) :(

Comment: Did you create the project using "e4 Application Project"?

Comment: @Baz:Tried to follow this http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse3RCP/article.html

Comment: That's for e3 RCP applications. As far as I understood you, you want to have an [e4 RCP application](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

Nebula CDateTime also requires the Nebula CWT (Common Widget Toolset) project.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem today with nebula-cDateTime. I realized, it isn't enough to add the nebula-plugin, you need to make sure your product fit it also.

Here:

1. Go to **"Run Configuration"** (I assume, you have a product-based start. If you use a feature-based start then add the nebula in feature also)
2. Select your product and move to **"Plug-ins"**-Tab
3. Push **"Validate Plug-ins"**. It'll show you the missing plugins.
4. Then hit the **"Add Required Plug-ins"**-Button, **"Apply"** and **"Run"**