# Eclipse RCP: Missing required plug-in during export

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When I try to export my Eclipse RCP product, I received the following error:

```
Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.pde.container.feature: Bundle org.apache.batik.dom.svg_1.6.0.v200805290154 failed to resolve.:
    Missing required plug-in org.apache.batik.css_0.0.0.
    Missing required plug-in org.apache.batik.dom_0.0.0.
    Missing required plug-in org.apache.batik.parser_0.0.0.
    Missing required plug-in org.apache.batik.util_0.0.0.
    Missing required plug-in org.w3c.css.sac_0.0.0.
    Missing required plug-in org.w3c.dom.smil_0.0.0.
    Missing required plug-in org.w3c.dom.svg_0.0.0.
```

I already tried to follow the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028573/eclipse-rcp-missing-constraint-bundle-error); but it didn't work.

The required bundle inside MANIFEST.MF of the plugin `org.apache.batik.dom.svg` which cause the error are:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.batik.dom.svg
Require-Bundle: org.apache.batik.css;version="[1.6.0,1.7.0)", 
    org.apache.batik.dom;version="[1.6.0,1.7.0)", 
    org.apache.batik.parser;version=" [1.6.0,1.7.0)", 
    org.apache.batik.util;version="[1.6.0,1.7.0)",
    org.w3c.css.sac;version="[1.3.0,1.4.0)",
    org.w3c.dom.smil;version="[1.0.0,1.1.0)",
    org.w3c.dom.svg;version="[1.1.0,1.3.0)" 
Export-Package: org.apache.batik.dom.svg;version="1.6.0",
    org.apache.ba tik.dom.svg12;version="1.6.0"
Bundle-Version: 1.6.0.v200805290154
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Are those plug-ins in your target platform? If they are what versions are they? The version requirements in the Require-Bundle you show are for fairly old versions of the plug-ins.

Comment: Yes, those are plugins in my target platform: `org.apache.batik.css (1.6.0.v200805290154)`, `org.apache.batik.dom (1.6.0.v200805290154)`, `org.apache.batik.parser (1.6.0.v200805290154)`, `org.apache.batik.util (1.6.0.v200805290154)`, `org.w3c.css.sac (1.3.0.v200805290154)`, `org.w3c.dom.smil (1.0.0.v200806040011)`, `org.w3c.dom.svg (1.1.0.v200806040011)`