# Eclipse e4 - Missing Constraint: Require-Capability: osgi.extender

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

When running my eclipse e4 application it shows that problems have been detected when validating.

[image: Missing Constraint]

This can be fixed by going to run configurations and selecting `Add Required Plug-ins` but this is more of a work around then a fix.

I've tried changing the versions and adding/removing plugins but can't figure out how to solve these errors.

A similar issue is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028573/eclipse-rcp-missing-constraint-bundle-error).

What could be causing this?

Comment: Why is 'adding required plug-ins 'just' a workaround? You need to have the correct plugins before things will work. The set of required plugins does vary between Eclipse releases, in this case it is the addition of org.apache.felix.scr that causes the issue.

Comment: The application should be set up so the developers don't have to do anything else to get it working. I've tried `Add Required Plug-ins` in the product file but that doesn't add all of them. In the run configuration it adds everything that is needed though.      
Also when we build the app it will use the information from the manifest etc and not the `Run Configuration` so that would be a problem too?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? What version of Eclipse is your target platform?

Comment: 2018-12 and the target platform is set to the `Running Platform`.

Comment: Not a direct solution but I find it much easier to use 'feature' based configuration both in the product file and the Run Configuration. The feature contents determine the plugins and should always be correct.

Comment: Do you know what is the cause of the current error?

Comment: The org.apache.felix.scr plugin provides the capability being complained about. This is a change from older releases which used a different plugin, and also requires changes to the start levels if the default is not being used. I don't know why Eclipse is not including this for you.

Comment: I've added the `org.apache.felix.scr` plugin and this has removed the previous problems. Instead of `osgi.extender` it now is complaining about `osgi.service`. This is for `org.eclipse.e4.ui.services` and `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find the missing plugins by comparing my run configuration before and after clicking `Add Required Plug-ins`.

There were 5 plugins missing that clicking `Add Required Plug-ins` in the product file didn't add.

```
org.apache.felix.scr
org.eclipse.equinox.event
org.eclipse.compare.core
org.eclipse.fx.osgi
org.eclipse.team.core
```

After adding these plug-ins to the product file and manifest the missing constraints problem was resolved.

Answer (score 9):

If you add `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` to your Required Plug-ins in `MANIFEST.MF` then this dialog will not show up at launch.

Comment: There isn't one available for `org.eclipse.equinox.ds`. There are multiple entries for `org.eclipse.equinox.*` but not `ds`.

Comment: Wow, they took it out. Kenneth Evans writes it is "in the 4.10 update site under Equinox Target Components" in this thread: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539655

Comment: This is almost it! I installed the `Equinox Target Components` then added `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` to the manifest. After adding required plugins it adds the `org.apache.felix.scr` plugin which fixes the problem as it is a dependency. Overall this can be avoided by adding `org.apache.felix.scr` without doing anything else but I end up with missing constraints as mentioned in the comments with Greg above. 

I get missing constraints for `osgi.service`. This is for `org.eclipse.e4.ui.services` and `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench`. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` is no longer used in the latest versions of Eclipse. It has been replaced with `org.apache.felix.scr`

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have any ideas for the next error I'm getting? I can create a separate question if that's easier. I'm having trouble fixing these errors as I'm not sure where to look so if you have any documents I should check out it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue with the same behaviour, that if "add missing dependencies automatically" these kind of missing dependencies where gone.
Adding org.apache.felix.src to launch config/product fixes this.

However: I have already the org.eclipse.e4.feature added to my product.
If org.apache.felix.src is of such importance - why is it not put into the feature as dependency of the feature?
Or asked the other way round: How should one resolve this without knowing that org.apache.felix.src is missing? There is no hint or something else that points to the missing dependency. Just the Require-Capability missing messages.
Is there a way to do "bughunting" that leads to the missing dependency I am not aware of?

Or would this rather be an issue to be asked within the eclipse forum to get an answer from the developers?

Comment: It looks as if the first paragraph of this answer contains a solution: "_Adding `org.apache.felix.src` to launch config/product fixes this._". I note that the `.src` part of your solution is different from the `.scr` mentioned in other existing answers. Is yours a typo, or a different solution? If it's just a typo then it's not a new answer (and should probably be removed). Also the rest of the answer is not actually an answer, but a series of new questions. These do not belong in a Stack OVerflow answer (and, as you suspect, they are probably not suitable for Stack Overflow, either).